# Docker Stack Deploy Does Not Work

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, docker-swarm

i am trying to deploy a stack to my docker swarm but it does not work. i call the command

```
sudo docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml server-test
```

but it gives me the error

```
unsupported Compose file version: 2
```

but when i run `docker-compose up`, it works fine. i then check the `docker-compose --version` which gives me:

```
docker-compose version 1.21.2, build a133471
```

this is the latest version as of writing this. i'm fairly new to docker so any guidance on this is appreciated.

my docker-compose.yml file is as follows:

```
version: '2'

services:
  caddy:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer:latest
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error refers to `version: '2'` in the first line of docker-compose.yml. You need to change syntax to at least `version: '3.0'` then  `docker stack` will work.

There is [upgrade guide](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#upgrading) for docker-compose.yml.